# In statement and values error with django

Tags: python, sql, django, templates, select

I tried to make a COUNT GROUP BY with django using the following statement

```
top_book = Borrow.objects.filter(beginDate__gte=str(weekAgoDate)).values('book').order_by().annotate(num_borrow=Count('book')).order_by('-num_borrow')[:5]
```

but when i try to access data in the template it doesn't give as output anything

```
{% for cont in top_book %}        
<tr>
<td><a href="/toplibrary/bookInfo/{{ cont.book.idBook }}/">{{ cont.book.title }}</a></td><td>{{ cont.book.isbn }}</td><td>{{ cont.book.author }}</td><td>{{ cont.book.editor }}</td>    

</tr>{% endfor %}
```

So i tried to do a IN statement with class Book to get all the info i Need about my book

```
top_books=Book.objects.filter(idBook__in=top_book)
```

But i get this error

```
"This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"
```

Could someone suggest a solution?

```
class Book(models.Model):
    idBook = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    isValid = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    linkDescr = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    editor = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    isbn = models.BigIntegerField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name="Categories")
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, verbose_name="Position")
    addedDate = models.DateTimeField()

class Borrow(models.Model):
    beginDate = models.DateField()
    renewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="BorrowHasUser")
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, verbose_name="BorrowHasBook")
    returnDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait, are you trying to get the most borrowed books?

Maybe this will make more sense:

```
top_book = Book.objects.annotate(num_borrow=Count('borrow')).order_by('-num_borrow')[:5]
```

If you have a `related_name` set on your `Borrow.book` field, use it instead of `borrow`.

Sorry I answered on auto-pilot first.

Comment: thanks, but what if I also want to have the attribute num_borrow in my template? Is there a solution?

Comment: thanks for your help, but it does not work. I don't have linked Book to Borrow but Borrow to Book. I edited my question with class declarement

Comment: for all the books it says that they have only 1 borrow

Comment: Could you `print Book.objects.annotate(num_borrow=Count('borrow')).order_by('-num_borrow').query`?